# Polygons are Jordan Measurable in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that Polygons are Jordan Measurable in $\mathbb R^2$

where we were just introduced to Jordan-Measurability that is defined as:

$M \subset \mathbb R^{d}$ is Jordan measurable if for any $\epsilon > 0$ figures $F, F^{'}\in \mathcal{F}^{d}$ exists (where $\mathcal{F}^{d}$ is the ring generated by the product of right-open intervals) where $F \subset M \subset F^{'}$ so that  $\lambda^{d}(F)-\lambda^{d}(F^{'})< \epsilon$

My idea: 
let $\epsilon >0$
I assume $M$ as a polygon can be written as: $M:=\{ x \in \mathbb R^{2}: Ax \leq b\}$

$M$ is further bounded and closed and hence for every inequality we can find a maximising $x^{i+}\in M$ as well as a minimizing $x^{i-}$ so that $A_{i.}x^{i+}=b_{i}$ where $A_{i.}$ is the i-th row vector. I would thus define my $F:=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{m}[x^{i-}+\frac{1}{2n},x^{i+}-\frac{1}{2n}[$ and $F^{'}:=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{m}[x^{i-}-\frac{1}{2n},x^{i+}+\frac{1}{2n}[$ where we chose $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ it is clear that $F, F^{'}\in \mathcal{F}^{d}$ as finite intersection as well as finite unions of half open intervals. Furthermore $F \subset M \subset F^{'}$ (I am unsure whether this is true) and note that: 
 $\lambda^{d}(F^{'})-\lambda^{d}(F)< \epsilon$

It is clearly not correct, I need some help.

Comment: Do you know that a bounded set is Jordan-measurable iff its boundary has Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: @Thorgott As it notion of Jordan measurability was only introduced by the definition above, I am only using the definition.

Comment: In that case, I would triangulate the polygon. Every triangle is the union of two right triangles and the Jordan Measure is invariant under isometries, so it suffices to prove that a right triangle whose orthogonal sides lie on the x- and y-axis (with corner at the origin) is measurable. That then looks like the graph of a linear function on some interval and similar to how one demonstrates integrability of such a function, one can show measurability of the graph with upper and lower approximating rectangles. This connection is no coincidence.

Comment: @Thorgott Do the upper and lower approximating rectangles I mentioned suffice? An answer would be rather helpful

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow your proof. You should justify your assumption on $M$. Is $A$ a $2x2$ matrix and $b$ a vector? If yes, is the inequality supposed to hold coordinate-wise? I don't really understand your claim about the maximizing and minimizing elements and their existence (in fact, it seems wrong to me). I also don't understand why you define F and F' as union and intersections of intervals when you want subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.